# how to store data on Firebase - Delphi XE 10

Tags: delphi, firebase, vcl, delphi-10-seattle, firedac

What is the best way to connect to Google´s Firebase DBaaS from Embarcadero Delphi XE 10 ?

I am not sure how to do it from AnyDAC.
Or if exists a component out there (i coundnt find one on search)

Any help?
thank you

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: DBaaS = Database as a Service. https://www.firebase.com/
if you try to find "firebase delphi" on google, you wont find any documentation about it. this is why i am coming to the community for help

Comment: As Puf said: "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: There is a `EMSFireDACClient` is that what you're looking for? See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/REST.Backend.EMSFireDAC.TEMSFireDACClient

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) was acquired by Google and now makes available many [tools and features](https://firebase.google.com/features/) (Cloud Messaging, Authentication, Realtime Database, Storage, Hosting etc...)
If you are looking for a service that store and sync app data in realtime, the Realtime Database it's for you. Realtime Database: "A cloud-hosted NoSQL database. Data is stored as JSON, synced across connected devices in milliseconds, and available when your app goes offline." . Firebase provides SDK library for Android, iOS and Web (Javascript). In addition makes available a REST API interface and, as [Robert Love](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93161/robert-love) said in previous post, [Firebase4Delphi](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi) (I wrote it) library provides access to the REST API in Delphi. [Here](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2016/06/simple-chat-messaging-system-with.html) there is an example of how to use library.

Comment: Robert, thanks for replying. Daniele, great job! In the link you provided there is a demo of RT chatting. what about one of storing/retrieving to the database ?

Comment: Thanks Diego! The chat demo stores and retrieves data directly from Firebase Realtime Database (see Fig. 2) . The URL shown in the picture indicate the Realtime Database ( a NoSQL database ).

Comment: Firebase4Delphi does support the persistent (socket) two way connection between Firebase and Delphi app?  Anybody has an example?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source project called [Firebase4Delphi](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi).  It provides access to the REST API in Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime a new open source library is available on *GitHub* for *Firebase*, *Firestore*, *Firebase Storage* and *Firebase Functions*:

Get more information on https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D